# Using Manipulate[ ] with physical units

Tags: manipulate, units

I'm a new user, and am trying to build a simple *Boyle's law* system in *Mathematica*. I want to include the units of the values, as I may need to perform some conversions later. If my quantities are a discrete list, they work fine. I cannot seem to get it to work for a slider. Can you help? I need this for work, and it's quite urgent. I've searched for a while before posting this question. Here's my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Text@Style[
   Grid[{
     {Row[{"Total fill volume is ", totalVolume}]},
     {Row[{"Delivery rate is ", deliveryRate}]},
     {Row[{"Product duration is ", 
        duration[totalVolume, deliveryRate]}]},
     {Row[{}]},
     {Row[{"Initial pressure is ", initialPressureG}]},
     {Row[{"Drop in pressure is ", pressureDrop, "%"}]}
     }, Alignment -> Left]
   ]
 ,
 {{totalVolume, Quantity[30, "ml"], "Total fill volume"}, 
  Quantity[{30, 45, 60, 90}, "ml"]},
 {{deliveryRate, Quantity[1, "ml/day"], "Delivery rate"}, 
  Quantity[{0.5, 1, 2, 3}, "ml/day"]},
 {initialPressureG, 0, 100},
 {{pressureDrop, 40, "Pressure drop"}, 0, 100, 5}
 ]
```

Instead of `initialPressureG` being a slider from `0` to `100`, I want it to be a slider from `0psi` to `100psi`. Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

Comment: Namitha, welcome to mma.se . Please include the missing function `duration` in your post.

Comment: why not just use `{Row[{"Initial pressure is ", initialPressureG, " Psi"}]}`?

Comment: ... or, if you want to display `lbf/(in)^2` instead of `psi` use `QuantityForm[QuantityUnit@Quantity@"psi", "Abbreviation"]` instead of " psi". If you wish, you can also change the control to `{initialPressureG, QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[0, "psi"]],  QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[100, "psi"]]}`

Comment: @kguler What does `duration` do?

If I use your option of changing the control, if and when I want to extract the value of what the user sets on the slider, would it have the dimension "psi"? Or would I have to set that separately in a calculation?

Comment: Hm. I was hoping that using `Evaluate[]` would fix the issue. It actually does assign the `lbf/(in)^2` to `initialPressureG` but the slider then displays as this:  

        `initialPressureG Manipulator[0,{0 lbf/in^2,1+0 lbf/in^2},AutoAction->False]`

Comment: Namitha, re `duration`, i meant that your posted code does not include the definition of the function `duration; so your code does not evaluate when we copy/paste it into a notebook.

Comment: I posted an answer showing what I get when I make changes in your code along the lines suggested above.

Comment: Thank you @kguler! Yep, you're right, I forgot `duration[]` but it doesn't affect any calculations - only used for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dur = Times; 
Manipulate[
 Text@Style[
   Grid[{{Row[{"Total fill volume is ", totalVolume}]}, 
         {Row[{"Delivery rate is ", deliveryRate}]}, 
         {Row[{"Product duration is ", dur[totalVolume, deliveryRate]}]}, 
         {Row[{}]}, {Row[{"Initial pressure is ", initialPressureG}]}, 
         {Row[{"Drop in pressure is ", pressureDrop, "%"}]}}, Alignment -> Left]],
   {{totalVolume, Quantity[30, "ml"], "Total fill volume"}, Quantity[{30, 45, 60, 90}, "ml"]}, 
   {{deliveryRate, Quantity[1, "ml/day"], "Delivery rate"}, Quantity[{0.5, 1, 2, 3}, "ml/day"]}, 
   {initialPressureG, Quantity[Range[0, 100, .01], "psi"], ControlType -> Manipulator}, 
   {{pressureDrop, 40, "Pressure drop"}, 0, 100, 5}]
```

[image]

Note: Use your function `duration` instead of `dur`.

Comment: Isn't using `QuantityMagnitude[]` the same as just using the numbers `0` and `100`? Does it make a difference to use `qM @ Quantity[0, "psi"]`?

Comment: @NamithaJassem, exactly ... if you just need the `"psi"` label you don't need `Quantity` or `qm@Quantity` in the control specification..

Comment: Namitha, please see the edited version.

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much!!